# R blogdown: figures generated in .Rmd file don't show when blog is displayed on R-bloggers

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, hyde

We successfully and easily [created a blog](https://github.com/easystats/blog) using blogdown for R. The blog looks great and works as expected.

The figures, generated automatically upon the rmarkdown knitting, are displayed properly as shown [here](https://easystats.github.io/blog/posts/bayestestr_presentation/) (see the second figure with the density plots, the first one (the logo) being inserted with a full URL).

However, when this post was reposted on R-bloggers, the image [doesn't show](https://www.r-bloggers.com/describe-and-understand-bayesian-models-and-posteriors-using-bayestestr/)...

As I supposed that it was an issue in the URL, I tried setting `relativeURLs` to `false` in the [config.toml](https://github.com/easystats/blog/blob/master/config.toml). Unfortunately, this made the image not rendering on the blog itself.

Being quite new to websites, I am not sure how what is wrong and how to address it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved a similar issue. I am hosting a [webpage](https://macstrelioff.github.io/MacStrelioff/data-science/twitter-poisson-processes-and-conjugacy/) through github using the hugo Academic template. There is a parameter in the 'params.toml' file called `math` that controls global LaTeX rendering. Setting `math=true` in the 'params.toml' file lead to an issue like that on the R-bloggers site, where it seemed like paths to images from .Rmd code chunks were no longer constructed properly. For me, this was fixed by setting `math=false` in the params.toml file. For pages that needed LaTeX rendering, I then included `math:true` in their YAML.