# Fixing broken relative links in RSS feed for blogdown posts using Hugo

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown, hugo-shortcode

Overall, the topic of my question is an old one: how to fix image paths to be absolute in RSS feed. As @Yihui notes, this is mostly a Hugo problem, not a blogdown problem, and is a problem everyone using R-bloggers will have. As this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68792824/broken-relative-links-in-rss-feed-for-blogdown-posts-using-hugo-asset-bundling) points out, there is no simple way to make RSS image paths be absolute in RSS, but to write them by hand in each post. @Yihui provided a much better solution (see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/384) and [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2037)) by using a Hugo shortcode and replacing `![](foo.png)` with `![]({{< blogdown/postref >}foo.png})` within Rmarkdown documents.

Everything seems fine, but when I do the replacement I get:

> Error: Error building site:
> "E:\path\blog\content\post\name_post\index.en.markdown:1:1":
> unrecognized character in shortcode action: U+003E '>'. Note:
> Parameters with non-alphanumeric args must be quoted

It seems that Hugo doesn't recognize the shortcode (or that it ends with last `}`). I checked `blogdown/postref.html` and it is up to date, I installed newest version of Hugo, updated blogdown and dependencies, ran `blogdown::check_site()` (and `blogdown::serve_site()`). Nothing helped.

Any idea where the error issue lies and how to fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
![]({{< blogdown/postref >}foo.png})
```

should be

```
![]({{< blogdown/postref >}}foo.png)
```

Comment: Thank you Yihui-sama for your help and for your briliant packages. Yea, I kind of figured that the brace was off and shortcode didn't end were it should have, but I am a lemming and didn't think to try to move it myself. It works perfectly. Btw, in the Github issues I linked this mistake creeped up in multiple posts.